# Add or update exchange 2010 attributes

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2010, adsi

I have created a custom attribute in ADUC, for user account called "Employee ID".

I want to add this field in outlook address book contacts and also make this visible in the Exchange attributes when I do a "Get-mailbox -identity user".

there is also the "Employee number" attribute in Exchange but I have suppressed its use, and using "employee ID" with a script instead.

I want assistance for
- Enabling the attribute in Exchange(2010) 
- Enable the attribute in Outlook Address book contact.

-pasha

Comment: you mean you wish to show that attribute in the addresbooks so that it comes up and can be searched?

Comment: yes, but just so you know the attribute is listing in ADUC, but not in Exchange attributes for mailbox.(Get-mailbox)
i want it to be listed in exchange and also be searched in the address book..

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can fine tune the attributes which are used on the Offline Addressbook (which is used by Outlook)

Per default you can get them via:

```
Get-OfflineAddressBook "Default Offline Address List" | Select "ConfiguredAttributes"
```

So in theory you might try to add it via:

1. Create a new Offline Adressbook

   New-OfflineAddressBook -Name 'Default Offline Address Book with custom fields' -Server 'Exchange01' -AddressLists '\Default Global Address List' -PublicFolderDistributionEnabled $false -VirtualDirectories 'Exchange01\OAB (Default Web Site)'
2. Get the current Attributes and add the new one

   $attr = (Get-OfflineAddressBook "Default Offline Address Book*").configuredattributes
   $attr.Add("employeeID,Value")
3. Put them Back into your new addressbook

   Set-OfflineAddressBook Default Offline Address Book with custom fields" -ConfiguredAttributes $attr
4. Generate it

   Get-OfflineAddressBook "Default Offline Address Book with custom fields" | Update-OfflineAddressBook
5. Assign it

   Get-DailboxDatabase MDB* | Set-MailboxDatabase -OfflineAddressBook "Default Offline Address Book with custom fields"

**BUT I haven´t tested it!**

Comment: Thanks much for your input..
i followed the steps: i have the attribute listed in ADUC, but when i execute the command to add the attribute(Step 3) i get below 
***The property "employeeID" couldn't be resolved as a well-known property name, Active Directory schema or LDAP attribute
 name, or numeric MAPI ID or property tag.***